# is it a good practice to close file descriptors on exit

Tags: c, coding-style, file-descriptor

If for some reason, I discover a fatal situation in my program, and I would like to exit with an error code.
Sometimes, the context of the fatal error is outside the scope of other file-descriptors.

is it a good practice to close these file descriptors?

As far as I know, these files are automatically closed when the process dies.

Comment: Design your system in such a way, that there is always the possibility to perform a clean shut-down. The latter includes freeing/unlocking any resources still in use by the system that is about to go down.

Comment: As import this rightly says explicit is always better than implicit!!

Comment: @alk This is a complicated legacy system, cascading errors is not possible, and refactoring is not an option.

Comment: C only guarantees that all files are closed if you exit either via the `exit` function, or a return from `main`.

Comment: @teppic so if process halts because of a SIGABRT some descriptor could still be considered "in use" by the OS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Files are automatically closed, but it's a good practice.

See valgrind on this example

```
david@debian:~$ cat demo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("demo.c", "r");
    return 0;
}
david@debian:~$ valgrind ./demo
==3959== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3959== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3959== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3959== Command: ./demo
==3959== 
==3959== 
==3959== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3959==     in use at exit: 568 bytes in 1 blocks
==3959==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 568 bytes allocated
==3959== 
==3959== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3959==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3959==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3959==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3959==    still reachable: 568 bytes in 1 blocks
==3959==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3959== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3959== 
==3959== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3959== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

As you can see, it raises a memory leak

On some circumstances you can make use of `atexit()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static FILE *f;

static void free_all(void)
{
    fclose(f);
}

static int check(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    atexit(free_all);
    f = fopen("demo.c", "r");
    if (!check()) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    /* more code */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `FILE` pointer returned by `fopen()` is not a file descriptor. It is a file stream, which has an associated buffer. So when your program returns from `main` without proper `fclose()` call you leave this memory leaked, as valgrind shows. The question about the _file descriptors_ remains unanswered.

Answer (score 21):

The classic guide to POSIX programming "Advanced programming in UNIX environment" states:

> When a process terminates, all of its open files are closed automatically by the kernel. Many programs take advantage of this fact and don't explicitly close open files.

You did not mention the OS in your question but such behavior should be expected from any OS. Whenever your program control flow crosses `exit()` or `return` from `main()` it is the system responsibility to clean up after the process.

There is always a danger of bugs in OS implementation. But, on the other hand, system has to deallocate way more than several open file descriptors at the process termination: memory occupied by the executable file image, stack, kernel objects associated with the process. You can not control this behavior from the user space, you just rely on its working-as-intended. So, why can't a programmer rely on the automatic close of the `fd`s?

So, the only problem with leaving `fd`s open may be the programming style question. And, as in the case of using `stdio` objects (i.e. stuff built around the system-provided file i/o), you may get (somewhat) disorienting alerts while valgrinding. As for the danger of leaking system resources, there should be nothing to worry about, unless your OS implementation is really buggy.

Answer (score 7):

> As far as I know, these files are automatically closed when the process dies.

Don't rely on that. Conceptually, when the process dies, it is **your responsibility** to free allocated memory, close non-standard file descriptors, etc. Of course, every sane OS (and even Windows) will clean up after your process, but that's not something to expect.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Suppose your main program is now a class in a separate program.  Now you just described a resource leak.  You're essentially violating encapsulation by relying on global program state, i.e. the state of the process - not your module, not a class, not an ADT, not a thread, but the whole process - being in a shutdown state.

Answer (score 4):

Every sane operating system (certainly any form of Linux, or Windows) will close the files when the program terminates. If you have a very simple program then you probably don't need to close files on termination. However closing the files explicitly is still good practice, for the following reasons:

1. if you leave it to the OS you have no control over the order in which the files are closed, which may lead to consistency problems (such as in a multi-file database).
2. if there are errors associated with closing the file (such as I/O errors, out of space errors, etc) you have no way of reporting them.
3. there may be interactions with file locking which need to be handled.
4. a routine to close all files can handle any other clean-up that the program needs at the same time (flushing buffers, for instance)

Answer (score 3):

C does guarantee that all open files will be closed if your program terminates normally (i.e. via `exit` or a return from `main`). However, if your program terminates abnormally, e.g. it's closed by the operating system due to using a NULL pointer, it's up to the operating system to close the files. Therefore it's a good idea to make sure files are closed once they're no longer needed in case of unexpected termination.

The other reason is resource limits. Most operating systems have limits on the number of files open (as well as many other things), and so it's good practice to return those resources as soon as they're no longer needed. If every program kept all its files open indefinitely, systems could run into problems quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Well this piece of goofy code could be christened as fd bomb since it opens a current dir in a newly preempted process and does not exit completely so no post mortem resources de-allocation like closing fd is happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *bin = NULL;
char *_argv = NULL;
char *_envp = NULL;

void handler(void) {
    execve(bin, &_argv, &_envp);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    bin = argv[0];
    _argv = *argv;
    _envp = *envp;

    printf("program name: %s pid: %d\n", argv[0], getpid());

    int fd = open(".", O_DIRECTORY);
    
    sleep(1);
    
    atexit(handler);

    return 0;
}
```

Tested in WSL2 with gcc as compiler.

Comment: Identifiers at file scope that start with `_` are [reserved](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3):  "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."  The processing of `argv` and `envp` are also very suspect and has [a bad code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) - the address of `_argv` does **not** refer to an array of pointers to strings that ends with a `NULL` pointer, thus the call to `execve()` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I accept all concerns stated above except one -- the piece of code has well defined behavior.Let's dissect it

Comment: @AndrewHenle We have a program that basically does nothing, obtaining fd of an cwd, sleeping for 1 sec, registering atexit callback and bailing out gracefully. In turn atexit callback does execve which replaces caller process image in memory with a new one right before calling process should have exited so no resources de-allocation is happening w/using OS gears. Basically it is an recursion call at the level of ABI.
So its pitfall I have expressed is well explained with this ^^^.

Comment: Anyway it is a foot shooter code which is just fun to experiment with but not to use in real projects. But the idea of self sustaining process w/o usage of supervisory services in the way of recursively calling yourself at exit sound interesting to me (as a dirty horny hack).

Comment: @AndrewHenle moreover **argv array is null terminated i.e. has null at argv[argc].

Comment: The `argv` array may be `NULL` terminated, but `_argv` is an "array" of just one element and it's guaranteed to **not** be `NULL` terminated.  `_argv` contains the *value* of `argv[0]`, which can't be `NULL` in your code because then `bin` would be `NULL` and then `execve()` would have a `NULL` first argument and immediately fail. Likewise, `_envp` contains the *value* of `envp[0]` which is almost certainly not `NULL`, so the single element "array" referred to by `&_envp` is also almost certainly guaranteed to not be `NULL` terminated.

Comment: You need to pass the exact values held in `argv` to `execve()`, not copy the value of `argv[0]` to another `char *` pointer and then pass the address of that pointer as a new `char *argv[]` to `execve()` - `_argv` is not an array.  Or create an entirely new `char *newArgv[]` of a large enough size to hold the arguments you want and a `NULL` terminater and pass that to `execve()`.  The same logic applies to `envp`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @desertnaut yes, u right! but it clearly shows the way of exploitation -- so probably the obvious conclusion could be like "yes, close your fds as soon as possible before returning from main()" isn't!