# Do i really need commented fclose() commands?

Tags: c, windows, crt

The following program was taken from *Windows System Programming* (Fourth Edition) by Johnson M. Hart:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *inFile, *outFile;
    size_t bytesIn, bytesOut;
    char rec[BUF_SIZE];

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Syntax : scp source destination.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    inFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (inFile == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    outFile = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (outFile == NULL) {
        perror(argv[2]);
        //fclose(inFile);
        return 3;
    }

    while ((bytesIn = fread(rec, 1, BUF_SIZE, inFile)) > 0) {
        bytesOut = fwrite(rec, 1, bytesIn, outFile);
        if (bytesIn != bytesOut) {
            perror("Fatal write error.");
            //fclose(inFile); fclose(outFile);
            return 4;
        }
    }

    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

It works the same with or without closing the files in the commented lines.
However, after having read previous posts I am not sure what is the best practice.
Let OS do its job or close them whenever I feel I should?
I am saying this because I have seen situations in windows GUI apps that, when I close the handles instead of the OS, I am causing a small glitch on the screen and I am essentially delaying the OS because I do the cleaning like many C++ books say.
I am not using anything windows here...it's a CRT implementation but still...

Comment: Modern OSs close the file descriptors that a terminating process did not close, so the commented line is not needed. However it's best practice to do so and I'd encourage you to do so.

Comment: This is a simple sequential file copy...but what happens when i have to do thousands of them?This would also be one small function in a professional program ...i guess what I am really asking is how do I really handle cleanup in  bigger programs ...how can I let OS help me clean ...what is the way?Do i gather thousand tiny cleanups in a bag and then say..hey OS ..this is for you...and if so how do I implement that?Maybe my question is too broad...but maybe there is some kind of guide out there by experienced developers...thank you for your answer.I will wait a little longer.

Comment: In C clean up has to be done by the program, the OS will only do clean up when the process exits without doing the clean up. Without code, it's difficult to tell how to manage that, but I think the best time to do clean is is when you don't need a resource anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246833/is-it-a-good-practice-to-close-file-descriptors-on-exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whole program ends after the fclose than it doesn't really make a difference. However, this usually isn't the case. You usually open a file write something into it and if you don't close it then you wont be able to reopen it nor will any other program be able to do so. Plus, if you just keep opening files then there will be a significant overhead at termination when the OS needs to close all of them. While, if you closed them when you no longer needed them then it would have evenly spread out over the course of time while the program was running.

Think of it as being in the library. If you take a bunch of books off the shelves and don't put them back, but than leave nothing really happens, because the librarian will put them back (although he will be occupied with it for quite some time). However, if you take a bunch of books and don't use them and you just keep piling them up on your desk and you don't leave for a long time, than for all those time the other guys in the library wont be able to use them.

The reason for using fclose even if your program does terminate is scalability, because if you don't and then you improve upon it, or use it as a function in an other program etc. then all those left out fcloses will come back to bite you in the ass.
Plus, it is more secure as well, because if you closed it then it cannot be accidentally written or read. It might seem silly if you haven't worked in a professional environment where multiple people work on the same code but defensive programming is a VERY useful and essential tool.

Answer (score 2):

Modern operating systems will free the resources of an terminating process that does not free, for example `malloc` allocated memory, file descriptors, etc. So in theory you don't need to close the descriptors if you are ending the program anyway.

However you are right, I consider it bad practice and I recommend that the programmer always frees resources and closes file descriptors, even for small and trivial programs like yours. Later on when you are working in a bigger project where you have to manage resources, you might forget to do clean up when it is really needed because you've learnt from trivial examples not to care about that. That's why I think it's a good practice to do so even for trivial examples like yours.

> I am saying this because i have seen situations in windows GUI apps that when i close the handles instead of the OS i am causing a small glitch on the screen and I am essentially delaying the OS because I do the cleaning like many C++ books say.

I don't know about that, perhaps you were closing the wrong file descriptors (or ones you are not supposed to close) or at the incorrect time. Without code it's difficult to say whether this is true or not.

Comment: This is a simple sequential file copy...but what happens when i have to do thousands of them?This would also be one small function in a professional program ...i guess what I am really asking is how do I really handle cleanup in  bigger programs ...how can I let OS help me clean ...what is the way?Do i gather thousand tiny cleanups in a bag and then say..hey OS ..this is for you...and if so how do I implement that?Maybe my question is too broad...but maybe there is some kind of guide out there by experienced developers...thank you for your answer.I will wait a little longer.

Comment: It is the OS which does the "clean up" anyhow, fclose makes a system call, which basically means that you tell the OS to close that file now. The same exact system call occurs if you don't do it and your program terminates. With fclose you essentially tell the OS that you no longer need that file, anyone can do whatever they please with it.

Comment: @strax In a larger program you have to do it yourself.