# Does the mmap field still exist when I kill the process？

Tags: process, operating-system, mmap

I use mmap() in a process, then I kill the process without close mmap. The mmap field still exist?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15248221/2626313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process's own mappings are closed. If it is a shared mmap, it does not destroy the mappings used by other processes.