# If you create a function which opens files, do those files automatically "fclose()" after the function has returned?

Tags: c

To further explain the concept, I have included an example function that opens files:

```c
int compare_files(const char *filenameone, const char* filenametwo)
{
    FILE *mainfile = fopen(filenameone, "r");
    FILE *checkerfile = fopen(filenametwo, "r");
    int value = 1;
    if (!mainfile || !checkerfile)
    {
        value = -1;
        goto END;
    }
    int letter, letter2;
    while ((letter = fgetc(mainfile)) != EOF && (letter2 = fgetc(checkerfile)) != EOF)
        if (letter != letter2)
        {
            value = 0;
            break;
        }
END:
    fclose(mainfile);
    fclose(checkerfile);
    return value;
}
```

In the above example, would I **need** to call `fclose()` for mainfile and checkerfile? Or would those files be closed once the function completes?

Comment: You need to `fclose()` ... or `exit()` or return from `main()` for proper file management by the OS. A abnormal program termination (or call to `_exit()`) may leave the files in a *abnormal* state.

Comment: You can check this similar question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246833/is-it-a-good-practice-to-close-file-descriptors-on-exit

Comment: If you ask about file closure as soon as_function_ returns, the answer is a big **no** (btw: it is absolutely common creating a function just to open files passing the file descriptors to the subsequent functions). Things change talking about _process_ termination. The answer is yes (look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430365/what-happens-to-file-descriptors-when-the-process-is-killed) - it refers to Unix/Linux, but I believe it can be exended to windows as well).

Comment: I know it's just an example, but there's still a bug: if one of the `fopen`s fails, the corresponding `FILE *` will be NULL and you must not attempt to fclose it.

Comment: pretty much nothing "happens automatically" in C,  the main exception would be releasing automatic storage when the function returns

Comment: in general, the use of `goto()` results in 'spaghetti' code.  The use of `goto()` makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer to "Does X happen automatically in C?" is: No

And so is it in this case. Usually, open files are closed when you reach the end of the main function or invoke the `exit()` function. Same thing with dynamically allocated memory. But if the program exits abnormally, for instance because division by zero or segmentation fault, this could cause trouble. However, there are environments where this does not happen. It's quite common in embedded systems.

So close your files when you're done with them. And free all allocated memory. It's a good habit.

I would write your function like this:

```
int compare_files(const char *filenameone, const char* filenametwo)
{
    int ret = -1;
    FILE *mainfile = fopen(filenameone, "r");
    if(!mainfile) goto EXIT1;
    FILE *checkerfile = fopen(filenametwo, "r");
    if(!checkerfile) goto EXIT2;

    ret = 1;
    // Not related to your question, but these should be int since
    // a char cannot hold the value EOF
    int letter, letter2;
    while ((letter = fgetc(mainfile)) != EOF && (letter2 = fgetc(checkerfile)) != EOF) {
        if (letter != letter2) {
            ret = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(checkerfile);
EXIT2:
    fclose(mainfile);
EXIT1:
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, on process exit, I would assume all resources are released, no? Otherwise, ok with your answer.

Comment: @Tarik but OP asked about _function_ return.

Comment: @klutt: In a hosted environment, it is guaranteed that open files are closed when you reach the end of `main`. Per C 2p018 5.1.2.2.3 1, reaching the `}` that terminates `main` is equivalent to returning with a value of 0, and returning from the initial call to `main` is equivalent to calling `exit`. Per 7.22.4.4 3, calling `exit` flushes streams with unwritten buffered data and closes all open streams.

Comment: "Usually, open files are closed when you reach the end of the main function, but it's not guaranteed". I would say, it is guaranteed because exiting main implies the death of the process.

Comment: If your phrasing “Usually, open files are closed when…” means “Returning from the initial call to `main` usually closes files,” then it is wrong in a hosted environment. If it means “The usual way to handle files is to let them be closed when `main` returns,” then it is dubious and is not good practice.

Comment: @Tarik: Freestanding C implementations, such as implementations in specialized embedded environments, might not clean up when a program terminates.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but in those environments the process termination probably mean _system reboot_.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Those implementations usually don't have stdio in the first place, so the question is moot.

Comment: Abnormal exit will generally close the file descriptors (or whatever the OS equivalent is), but won't call stdio `fclose()`, so it won't flush buffers for instance.

Comment: Recommend `char letter, letter2;` --> `int letter, letter2;` to avoid infinite loop when `char` is _unsigned_ as `(letter = fgetc(mainfile)) != EOF` is never true.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: And if `char` is signed it will terminate early if character 255 is ever encountered.  Either way it certainly needs to be `int`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: Unloading a Windows DLL is an example of a program exit that doesn't clean up, on modern systems .

Comment: when an error occurs, the user should be notified.  This is best done via a message to `stderr`.  When the error is from a C library function, like `fopen()`, should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.  Suggest : `FILE *mainfile = fopen( filenameone, "r" ); if( ! mainfile ) { perror( "fopen to read mainfile failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }   FILE *checkerfile = fopen( filenametwo, "r" ); if( ! checkerfile ) { perror( "fopen to read checkfile failed" );  fclose( mainfile ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: @user3629249 Sure, but the code is easy to modify for that. I thought it was cleaner to leave that part out. Besides, it's not obvious that you want to quit the program on failure to read a file. The function `compare_files` obviously returns -1 on failure, so all that can be handled by the calling function. `int r = compare_files(file1, file2); if(r==-1) { perror("Error reading file"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: the value is `errno` is modified by most C library functions, so if the call to `perror()` is not immediately after the statement that produced the error, then the resulting message is (usually) not correct.

Comment: @user3629249 Nevertheless, it's quite easily solved if you really need it, but I thought it would be overkill to include all that in this answer, but you're welcome to write your own answer.